# c# referring to array parameter

Tags: c#, arraylist

I'm still beginner  in programing and trying to list locked domain users but not sure how can I refer to parameter of counts in array

could you please help ?
part of the code:

```
else if (s.StartsWith("lookup"))
 {
   var lockedUsers = new List<UserPrincipal>();
   using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "test.local"))
   {
    GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "Domain Users");
    foreach (var userPrincipal in grp.GetMembers(false))
                            {
                                var user1 = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userPrincipal.SamAccountName);
                                if (user1 != null)
                                {
                                    if (user1.IsAccountLockedOut())
                                    {
                                        lockedUsers.Add(user1);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                            console.writeline(lockedUsers[0].samaccountname);
```

the problem is by using `lockedUsers[0].samaccountname` I'm getting only first item (user) obviously but how to refer to every count ? there is a wildcard or something that I can use ?  I tried foreach but not sure how to implement as I want to get the .SamAccountName parameter of each counted lockedUsers.

Output should be the value of SamAccountName (for each count in lockedUsers)

Thanks

Comment: So what exactly should your output be? Another array of `SamAccountName`?

Comment: Output should be the value of SamAccountName (for each count in lockedUsers)

Comment: `lockedUsers.ForEach((lu) => { Console.WriteLine(lu.SamAccountName); })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical solution will look like this:

```
foreach (var u in lockedUsers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(u.SamAccountName);
}
```

Or:

```
for (int i=0; i<lockedUsers.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(lockedUsers[i].SamAccountName);
}
```

There's also some clever ways to do it, like:

```
lockedUsers.ForEach((lu) => { Console.WriteLine(lu.SamAccountName); })
```

...(thanks Ron) or...

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n", lockedUsers.Select( u => u.SamAccountName )));
```